# How to input b with stroke?

Tags: xetex, symbols

I want to use the symbol ƀ (b with stroke) in my document. I use it for the blank symbol in the formal definition of Turing machines.

I use XeLaTeX, so I should be able to use the Unicode symbol, but I don't know how to enable the font for it in math mode.

Right now, I use the following, which works, but is quite ugly:

```
\newcommand{\blank}{\raisebox{0.8ex}{-}\kern-0.4em b}
```

What do I need to do in order to use the Unicode character in my document?

Comment: What text and math fonts are you using? Some have the glyph.

Comment: math font is cmmil0, text fonts are David CLM for Hebrew and DejaVu Sans for English. I need the glyph in math mode - do you know which math fonts have it, and how to switch to them?

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example, with some (English) text and math, just to understand better your setting?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to egreg pointing me towards other fonts, I came up with the following:

```
\newcommand{\blank}{\fontspec{Gentium}{\textit{ƀ}}}
```

I picked Gentium since it has a glyph that fits in well with the CM fonts, but other fonts work as well.

Comment: It's better to say `\newfontfamily{\gentium}{Gentium}` in the preamble and change the definition into `\newcommand{\blank}{{\gentium\textit{ƀ}}}` so that the code for defining a font family will be done only once.